# How do I make an Android EditView 'Done' button and hide the keyboard when clicked?

Tags: android, keyboard

When the user clicks on the `EditView`, Android opens the keyboard so that user can write in the `EditView`.

The problem is, when the user is done writing, there is no way to hide the keyboard. The user has to press the back button to hide the keyboard.

Is there a way to display a `Done` button on the keyboard that will hide the keyboard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable "Next" button on a EditText software keyboard (replace with "Done" button)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568637/how-to-disable-next-button-on-a-edittext-software-keyboard-replace-with-done)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Use [TextView.setImeOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setImeOptions(int)) and pass it actionDone.
like `textView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);`

Comment: `textView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);`

Comment: I had to add `textView.singleLine(true)` to get this to work programmatically.

Comment: but this is deprecated since android 2.3

Answer (score 190):

First you need to set the **`android:imeOptions`** attribute equal to **`actionDone`** for your target EditText as seen below. That will change your ‘RETURN’ button in your EditText’s soft keyboard to a ‘DONE’ button.

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edittext_done"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter some text"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:singleLine="true"
    />
```

Comment: @Michael removed that link. Thanks

Comment: I had to add `android:singleLine="true"` to get this to work via xml

Comment: android:singleLine is deprecated. Use android:maxLines="1".

Comment: Yes @FariborZ singleLine is deprecated now.

Comment: Important note: singleLine is not the same as maxLines. This misconception causes a lot of issues for everyone, we need to note that everywhere.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879471/android-singleline-vs-maxlines

Comment: This works for me if I also set android:singleLine, but not if I use android:maxLines instead. The only non-deprecated way I found to get the Done button to appear is to configure the EditText programmatically rather than in XML.

Comment: If this is not working for you, check if android:inputType = "text"

Answer (score 88):

Include **both** `imeOptions` **and** `singleLine`:

```
<EditText 
   android:id="@+id/edittext_done"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:imeOptions="actionDone"
   android:singleLine="true"
   />
```

Answer (score 39):

**For getting the done Button**

`editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);`

and

`android:inputType="text"` in the xml

**For handling on done clicked from keyboard**

```
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event){
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                // Your action on done
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

`

Answer (score 36):

```
android:imeActionLabel="Done" 
android:singleLine="true"
```

In the XML file works just fine. But this will also cause the `editText` to keep typing in a single line which you may not want. So adding following to your code will make sure that you won't end up typing everything on a single line.

```
mainText.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
mainText.setMaxLines("Maximum integer value that you want to provide");
```

Comment: Thanks, Demo was on 12 , time was 11:58 and you fixed my issue on 11:59 :p

Comment: android:singleLine = "true" has been deprecated. So use, android:lines="1"

Answer (score 15):

Use this:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: Yes...otherwise how is one going to distinguish going to the next line versus closing the keyboard?

Comment: This is what ended up working for me. I decided to error with having `actionDone` in there as well, just in case some devices react differently.

Answer (score 12):

Use These two lines to your `EditText`

```
android:imeActionLabel="Done"
android:singleLine="true"
```

or you can achieve it Programmatically by this line.

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

Answer (score 11):

### Kotlin Solution

The direct way to handle the hide keyboard + done action in Kotlin is:

```
// Set action
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        // Hide Keyboard
        val inputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
        true
    }
    false
}
```

### Kotlin Extension

Use this to call `edittext.onDone {/*action*/}` in your main code. Keeps it more readable and maintainable

```
edittext.onDone { edittext.hideKeyboard() }

fun View.hideKeyboard() {
    val inputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}

fun EditText.onDone(callback: () -> Unit) {
    // These lines optional if you don't want to set in Xml
    imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
    maxLines = 1
    setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            callback.invoke()
            true
        }
        false
    }
}
```

### Additional Keyboard Extensions

If you'd like more ways to simplify working with the keyboard (show, close, focus): [Read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977187/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-when-activity-starts/59780712#59780712)

> #### Don't forget to add these options to your edittext Xml, if not in code

```
<EditText ...
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

> Need **`inputType="textMultiLine"`** support? [Read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59779604/974045) and don't add `imeOptions` or `inputType` in Xml

Answer (score 7):

If the property does not change for the widget it may be better to use like 
`android:imeOptions="actionDone"` in the layout `xml` file.

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
android:imeActionLabel="Done"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 6):

I have to point that out as a lot of people can struggle into that without knowing the problem.

If you want the kb to hide when clicking `Done`, and you set `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` & `android:maxLines="1"` **without** setting your EditText `inputType` it will **NOT** work as the default `inputType` for the EditText is not `"text"` as a lot of people think.

so, setting only `inputType` will give you the results you desire **whatever** what you are setting it to like `"text"`, `"number"`, ...etc.

Answer (score 5):

For the code:

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

Answer (score 5):

ActionDone is use when click in next button in the keyboard that time 
keyboard is hide.Use in Edit Text or AppcompatEdit

**XML**

1.1 If you use AppCompatEdittext

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

1.2 If you use Edittext

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

**JAVA**

```
EditText edittext= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

then you must use

```
android:inputType="text"
```

then only you can see Action Done button in Keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can set custom text to that little blue button. In the xml file just use

```
android:imeActionLabel="whatever"
```

on your EditText.

Or in the java file use

```
etEditText.setImeActionLabel("whatever", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

I arbitrarily choose **IME_ACTION_DONE** as an example of what should go in the second parameter for this function. A full list of these actions can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html).

It should be noted that this will not cause text to appear on all keyboards on all devices. Some keyboards do not support text on that button (e.g. swiftkey). And some devices don't support it either. A good rule is, if you see text already on the button, this will change it to whatever you'd want.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your view

```
<EditText 
    ....
    ....
    android:imeOptions="actionDone" 
    android:id="@+id/edtName"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any button at all (e.g. you are developing a GUI for blind people where tap cannot be positional and you rely on single/double/long taps):

```
text.setItemOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE)
```

Or in Kotlin:

```
text.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE
```