# How to disable "Next" button on a EditText software keyboard (replace with "Done" button)

Tags: android, android-edittext, soft-keyboard

I have a bunch of EditTexts in my Android application, each with InputMethod set to numberSigned. My target device does not have a hardware keyboard and uses the software keyboard for numeric entry. Android replaces the standard "Done" button to the right of the entry box with a "Next" button. How can I use "Done" instead?

Comment: I need to disable the next button. for that what can i do? i dont need done button in that place. Thanks

Comment: @SivakumarPurushothaman I can't test for you at the moment, but does actionNone work?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Try adding `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` to your `EditText`.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions)

Comment: but after selecting the text in edittext, Done button changes in to EDIT button and show cut,copy,paste..how to disable this.

Comment: What about Multi-Line EditTexts? This doesn't seem to work for them. :/

Comment: @SheharyarNaseer the input type for a multiline EditText needs to be the following in your EditText XML: `android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"`. Then the `android:imeOptions` will be work.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this.
I face some issue if i am wrong please correct me ,
This work in some device and not some of.
In HTC and Asus that Done not shown and in Samsung device that Done Visible. :)

Comment: Note : This solution is also working well for Xamarin : YourEditText.ImeOptions = Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Done;

Answer (score 55):

This can also be accomplished in code with:

```
myEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```