# how to add Go button in android SoftKeyBoard and its functionality?

Tags: android

i want to put "Go" button in android appliation softkeyboard

for search and other related scenarios can any one guide me how to achieve this? with example.

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: i thought it's something automaticly...

Comment: See this question from a couple of days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568637/how-to-disable-next-button-on-a-edittext-software-keyboard-replace-with-done

Answer (score 26, accepted):

finally i used...

```
EditText SearchEditText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMapSearch); 
SearchEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener(){  

    @Override 
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) { 
        if(arg1 == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH)  
        { 
            // search pressed and perform your functionality.
        }
        return false; 
    } 

});
```

Comment: Just to add a point, if you're keyboard shows a DONE button at the bottom right, use EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE instead.

Comment: A link to the documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html#Action

Answer (score 16):

If your question is that you have an EditText or editable TextView, and you want the action right button on the softkeyboard to read "Go" then add this attribute to your EditText/TextView

```
android:imeActionLabel="actionGo"
```

note that it will also have to be a single line TextView as otherwise the action button will be a carriage return selector (an arrow).

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: actually i want to perform functionality like pressing search button on activity on this soft key board button.

Comment: @Jim Blackler How can I make an action when user clicks the actionGo button in keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

I used

```
android:imeOptions="actionGo"
```

and to handle go action I ma using

```
etSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    //your functionality 

                    // hide virtual keyboard
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(etSearch.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am doing same this for "send":

Use this class in your layout :

public class ActionEditText extends EditText
{
    public ActionEditText(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

```
public ActionEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ActionEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs)
{
    InputConnection conn = super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
    outAttrs.imeOptions &= ~EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION;
    return conn;
}
```

}

In xml:

```
<com.test.custom.ActionEditText
            android:id="@+id/postED"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:hint="@string/msg_type_message_here"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
```