# Opening Keypad with GO

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad, imeoptions

Hi I want to open keypad when the `EditText` is focused , with `GO` in place of Next and Done Buttons.

I used

```
            android:imeOptions="actionGo"
```

in `EditText` xml tag but it's only showing an arrow not GO.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add Go button in android SoftKeyBoard and its functionality?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577956/how-to-add-go-button-in-android-softkeyboard-and-its-functionality)

Comment: if you're keyboard shows a DONE button at the bottom right, use `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard itself decides what to show, based on its own set of choices.  There is no way to force it to show anything, and not all keyboards will decide based on the same things.  You can improve your odds by only using 1 of those options and by making sure its not multiline (many keyboards will not remove their enter key in a multiline edit field), but its still up to the keyboard.

Comment: thanks for reply but in default browser when keypad open its showing GO

Comment: That's great.  That's one keyboard and one browser.  I'm saying there's no way to force that for all keyboards, and what an individual keyboard decides to do is different for every keyboard.  And please don't say you're just using the default-  different OEMs ship with different defaults.

Comment: yes it worked for me what i was doing wrong , EditText was multiline so it was showing Enter when I changed it to singleLine it showed GO.