# How do I get the done button to appear on the soft keyboard?

Tags: android

So, I do not see a done button on the soft-keyboard. There is the standard enter key, but from my reading I am lead to believe that there could be/should be a done button (when working with an AutoCompleteTextView at least. I have tried adding the following line to my xml, but to no avail:

```
android:imeActionLabel="Done"
```

I know Im missing something pretty huge, what is it?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did u get any solution? Your accepted solution is not working for me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer was to include

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

in the xml for the AutoCompleteTextView. This switches the enter key for next if there are multiple edittexts (and done for the last one), or for done if there is only one edittext.

Comment: Only ... Android sometimes gets "confused" and thinks there's multiple edittexts when there aren't :(.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question:

- [Disable Next button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568637/how-to-disable-next-button-on-a-edittext-software-keyboard-replace-with-done)

Comment: I tried the solution in there, my softkeyboard still lacks a done button. I am quite confused. I have also tried to add it using java: autocomplete.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);" but no luck there either