# Stopping the keyboard prompt for my second text field on Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm making a basic android app to convert the input from kilometers to miles, or miles to kilometers. The issue I'm having is that when I select one of the editText fields and enter a value, it automatically jumps into the second editText field prompting for input.

Is there a way to stop the second prompt from occurring? I'm hoping there is a simply attribute I can add into the XML to resolve this issue.

XML Code on the two editTextFields:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
android:ems="10"
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2"
android:layout_marginTop="45dp" 

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
android:ems="10"
android:id="@+id/editText2"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
```

Comment: this might fix your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568637

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Anthony!

Adding

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

worked.