# Listener for Done button on EditText?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

If I have an EditText and I want to listen for if the user presses the "done" button on the keypad.. how would I do this?

Comment: Point to consider, the phone might have a physical keyboard, so the user might never press the done button on the keyboard, have you thought about doing your operation based on focus loss or editText editing end?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60989441/878126

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Code is

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

In that 'edittext' is id of textfield

Check out this link [Simply set setOnKeyListener to your editText](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html)

Comment: Hi Dinash. Just posting a link generally isn't helpful. It's better to provide some sample code which answers the askers question and then link to the source article as reference or for further reading.

Comment: Hi Chris i though you can find the answer from that link itself but still i give an exact working code available in the link itself... Code is  final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); return true;}return false;}}); Hope you can find it helpful... In that 'edittext' is id of textfield

Comment: It will not work on custom keyboard. setOnKeyListener will not be called on some custom keyboards.

Comment: It does not work for some of my devices or keyboard software.

Comment: "event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN" is deprecated

Comment: Does not work on Samsung S20

Answer (score 169):

Dinash answer is nice, but it is not working on all devices. Below code works fine for all devices

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: this should be accepted answer - it the one that works on Samsung s4

Comment: Addition: The xml tag " android:imeOptions="actionDone" " needs to be set on the EditText in question. Works great - thanks!

Answer (score 26):

### Kotlin Extension Solution

The base way to handle the done action in Kotlin is:

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        // Call onDone result here
        true
    }
    false
}
```

### Kotlin Extension

Use this to call `edittext.onDone {/*action*/}` in your main code. Keeps it more readable and maintainable

```
edittext.onDone { submitForm() }

fun EditText.onDone(callback: () -> Unit) {
    // These lines optional if you don't want to set in Xml
    imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
    maxLines = 1
    setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            callback.invoke()
            true
        }
        false
    }
}
```

> #### Don't forget to add these options to your edittext Xml, if not in code

```
<EditText ...
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

> If you need **`inputType="textMultiLine"`** support, [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59779604/974045)

Comment: Just as a note to everyone, android:imeOptions="actionDone" does not perform uniformly across all devices, I have explicitly avoided it as much as possible as older devices with working key listeners begin to ignore them when this is active. I also find it can tab you to weird places, it also was picking up the backspace key on the Samsung S20

Comment: You should add explicit return@setOnEditorActionListener cuz "if" isn't last statement

Answer (score 9):

The [same Jone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37225076/6352712) answer, but with replaced lambda:

```
etPointCombatFirst.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
```

Answer (score 7):

Based on the response of Asad Rao, I created this KOTLIN extension function.

```
fun TextView.onClickKeyboardDoneButton(funExecute: () -> Unit) {
    this.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
        when (actionId) {
            EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE -> {
                funExecute.invoke()
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
myEditText.onClickKeyboardDoneButton{myFunctionToExecuteWhenUserClickDone()}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rx way to do this:

```
fun EditText.onImeActionDoneClicks(): Observable<Unit> {
    return Observable.create { emitter ->
        setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                emitter.onNext(Unit)
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        }
    }
}

compositeDisposable += lastEditText.onImeActionDoneClicks().subscribe {
    toast("onImeDoneClicks")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This Kotlin version should work on all devices:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        // Do something
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```