# How to change the focus from last edit text field to a button on clicking done in soft input?

Tags: android

I want to change the focus from edit-text field to a submit button when done is clicked on the soft input.

I've the following code :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="5sp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Driver + Conductor :"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/bus_driver_above60"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Driver"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/bus_conductor_above60"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/bus_conductor_above60"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Conductor"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:nextFocus="@+id/bus_above60_btn"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bus_above60_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#3498DB"/>
```

Here in the code,

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/bus_conductor_above60"
```

changes the focus from Driver Edit text field to Conductor Edit text field.

But after Conductor Edit text field, there is a Calculate button - bus_above60_btn.

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/bus_above60_btn"
```

is not changing the focus from Conductor Edit text field to the button below that field.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I think `nextFocusDown` works only for EditText, not for Button. I think you will have to use `setOnEditorActionListener` on the EditText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to make button focused on *Done* action, first you must set your buttons `focusableInTouchMode` as `true`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bus_above60_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#3498DB"/>
```

Now in your `EditText`'s `OnEditorActionListener`, make button focused when done clicked:

```
bus_conductor_above60.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int action, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if(action == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
            bus_above60_btn.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks man. This worked!
But the focus is being overlapped by the banner ad. Can I make anything to bring the focus above the banner ad?

Comment: setting `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` for the banner ad may fix it

Comment: No it is not working!!
Button is being scrolled up and being focused just above the soft-keyboard but at the same position, there is banner ad which blocks the view

Comment: can you share picture of it?

Comment: On last edit-text focus -> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_acM7_FSVJyM0xVcEpXYzZkVm8  |  Ad blocks the view button -> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_acM7_FSVJySkNYWlExeVU3aHc  | When Scrolled, the button is visible ->  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_acM7_FSVJyWmxraWNLVFNiX0U

Comment: Is there any way where I can make to scroll down till bottom when the done button in the soft keyboard is clicked? @SiSa

Comment: The soft key is not hiding after click on Done button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154223/discussion-between-sisa-and-avid).

Answer (score 1):

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/bus_conductor_above60"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
           />
```

In your code

```
bus_above60_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        sameFunction();
                    }
                });

bus_conductor_above60 = findViewById(R.id.bus_conductor_above60);

bus_conductor_above60 .setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                        sameFunction();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work if all components are in same layout. So firstly include your button in same layout where other editTexts placed then try.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik there are two ways for getting your goal

## 1. My layout is working exactly as you want:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etUsername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:hint="@string/username"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"  />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The reason for it, [from documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), is the following:

> Focus movement is based on an algorithm which finds the nearest
>   neighbor in a given direction. In rare cases, the default algorithm
>   may not match the intended behavior of the developer. In these
>   situations, you can provide explicit overrides by using these XML
>   attributes in the layout file [...]

So if you put the button in the same layout of the edittexts, it should manage the next focus automatically.

## 2. Manage the "next" click in the `editText`

[Taken from this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5677676/4700782)

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps!