# How do I run a method once a user has confirmed their input?

Tags: java, android

Im making a program where a user has to search through some of my data.

I've created an edit view for the user to put their text in to, but I want to run a method once the user has confirmed their input.

How do I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a confirm button? If yes, then use its `onClickListener`...

Comment: set OnClickListener on confirm-button and editText.getText().toString() once clickListener onClick is called

Comment: Please show us some code first

Comment: @deHaar I want to use the confirm button on the users keyboard.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster There isn't any code. This is the start of my activity.

Comment: Then read the documentation of EditText first.

Comment: Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could [edit], rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677563/listener-for-done-button-on-edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to add a search feature , why not use a search view instead.

Comment: I actually didn't realise android had a search view. Thank you, ill use this.

Answer (score 0):

there are many options to do this, i am writing 3 options below.

`1 - If you have confirm button then use its onclicklistener for you method call.`

`2 - If you don't have confirm button then add focusChangeListener in edittext and call you method when edittext focus is lost.`

`3 - You can use a timerTask like when user stopped typing for 2 second (we assume that user input is done) you can call your method`

Example:

```
    edt_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // user is typing: reset already started timer (if existing)
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // Search Logic
                       if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty())
                       // Your Function call
                }
            }, 500); // 350ms delay before the timer executes the "run“ method from TimerTask
        }
}
```