# Android Soft keyboard action button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

My layout has 4 EditText views and a submit Button view. I need to have "Next" button for the first 3 EditText's and a "Done" button for 4th EditText field in place of a "New Line" key of soft keyboard.

How can this be done?

Comment: Are they Multi-line? and what was the version of Android that you were using? just asking...

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In your layout, just set the XML attributes `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` for your first three text boxes and `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` for the last one.

See: [android:imeOptions documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions)

Also, there's a small XML example in the [training docs](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html#Action).

Comment: Hi Martin, android:imeOptions="actionNext" is working fine for the EditText's with android:inputType="text",  But for EditText with android:inputType="textMultiLine" not.

Comment: @Venkat, you could try `flagNavigateNext` instead: "...allows the IME to be multiline (with an enter key) as well as provide forward navigation..." (see first link above).

Comment: Hi Martin, i'm gettting "Error: string types not allowed" by using android:imeOptions="flagNavigateNext" for EditText

Comment: I get the same here :-( -- Looks like it's only available in API Level 11 or higher. (The documentation filter seems to be broken on that page, but is working for the corresponding Java constants here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html)

Comment: Hi Martin, then cant we add "Next" button for multiline EditText?

Comment: It would seem not. Even with API Level 11, the keyboard doesn't have to obey flagNavigateNext if it doesn't have space.

Looking at a few apps on my phone, it seems common to have the multiline box last, with a visible "Done" or "Send" button below it (e.g. Email app).

Comment: Thanks for the training docs link, I realised I was looking for `EditorAction`. I managed to get the Done keyboard button to execute my login function like this on Xamarin:

`var passwordField = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.passwordField);`

`passwordField.EditorAction += (sender, args) => { if (args.ActionId == ImeAction.Done) { // login action`
`};`

[This answer helped me alot too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317083/edittext-setoneditoractionlistener)

Answer (score 6):

to navigate the focus to the next edit field add

> android:imeOptions="flagNavigateNext"

and for dismissing the softkey with done click add

> android:imeOptions="actionDone"

on your layout :)

Answer (score 3):

Add `android:singleLine="true"` in your button xml

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
EditText nextText = new EditText(this)
{
    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(final EditorInfo outAttrs)
    {
        outAttrs.imeOptions |= EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT;
        return (super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs));
    }
};

EditText doneText = new EditText(this)
{
    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(final EditorInfo outAttrs)
    {
        outAttrs.imeOptions |= EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE;
        return (super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs));
    }
};
```

It first one will take the user to the next field in the layout that accepts text. The second will close the IME (the soft keyboard).