# Enter and Return button in a single keyboard in android

Tags: android, keyboard, return, enter

I need my soft keyboard input to have both return button AND done button so that the user can write paragraphs in my `EditText` and click on `Done` to close the keyboard. Is this possible?

I've tried:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

together but it didn't work.

PS: I'm testing on Samsung keyboard type.

Answer (score 0):

No, I believe it's not possible prior to API level 11 (3.0).

The same issue cropped up here (discussed in the comments to the accepted answer):

[Android Soft keyboard action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007204/android-soft-keyboard-action-button/6007433)

From the final comment:

```
Looking at a few apps on my phone, it seems common to have the multiline box last, with a visible "Done" or "Send" button below it (e.g. Email app).
```