# Force an "OK" button on the Android keyboard?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview, android-keypad, android-inputtype

I have a RecyclerView with an EditText in each row, where each EditText has the attribute

`android:inputType = "numberSigned|numberDecimal"`.

I want the user to easily be able to change any value(s) they want. However it's a little awkward on the keyboard because there doesn't seem to be a plain "I'm done changing this number, so hide the keyboard now" button.

If I press Back, it minimizes the app. I have to continually press the "OK button" that is there, but all this does is carry forward to the next EditText.

Comment: if you press back while the keyboard is up only the keyboard should be dismissed, are you sure you are not doing anything with the back button yourself?

Comment: Nothing strange as far as I can tell

Comment: I'm an idiot. I've been pressing the stupid two-square "look at the task manager" button instead of the back button.

Comment: you can btw control what's supposed to happen on pressing the keyboard's ok button: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007204/android-soft-keyboard-action-button

Comment: Very helpful to know! Thanks