# Multiline text input with a Done/Submit button on keyboard on Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The multiline text input for Android has only the carriage return button on the keyboard in place of the Done button. Is there any way to have a multiline text input with a done button also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible. With multiline input on Android, the enter key is the only way to put a line break.

See also [Multi-line EditText with Done action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986387/multi-line-edittext-with-done-action-button)

Answer (score 0):

**add this in your activity.java file within oncreate method after initialize**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        EditText option1_edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

       edt1.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
       edt1.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

}
```

**Add this line in the .XML file**

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```