# imeOptions doesn't work with MultiLine text?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-xml, imeoptions

Trying to add the attribute `android:imeOptions="actionSend"` on my EditText, and I want the text to adjust and create new lines as the user types.  I get multiple lines when I add:
`inputType="textMultiline"`, however, I do not get the send button for imeOptions.  When I replace textMultiline with `inputType="textImeMultiline"`, then the send button shows for imeOptions, but the text does not go onto multiple lines.

Is there anyway to make android not be a pain in the add and accept `imeOptions="actionSend"` on an EditText with *multiple lines*

Comment: If the send button is shown, I currently don't known if there is any way to include a return button that takes you to the next line.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41022589/6891637) works well.