# EditText multiline with "next view button" instead of "new line button"

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-view

Goal is to use multiline `EditText` with `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` and with "next view button" such as `android:inputType="text"` (see picture 2).

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/addAffirmationContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLength="255"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" />
```

I tried many combinations with:
`android:inputType, singleLine, nextFocusDown, nextFocusUp, nextFocusLeft, nextFocusRight, nextFocusForward, imeOptions, lines`, but `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` always forces new line button.

Tested on Nexus 5 Android 7.

Picture 1.: new line button:
[image: new line button]

Picture 2.: next view button:
[image: next view button]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the same as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41022589/4759619):

In code:

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

and in xml:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Comment: That's the correct answer! The solution did the trick. The only thing I wouder is why this combination gives us that behaviour? In fact we set inputType in code as a text reassigning inputType of xml which is textMultilane and in the end it's still acts as multiline but with action option. Could someone tell me what is exactly happening?

Comment: Thank you! I've been cracking my head over it and with your answer I finally got it!

Answer (score 0):

These three lines in combination should replace your "enter" with "next"

```
<EditText 
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext" />
```

Android have a lot of`"android:imeOptions`" to specify the keyboard action button

```
android:imeOptions="actionGo"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:imeOptions="actionPrevious"
android:imeOptions="actionSend"
```

and there are even more

Comment: I do not want block Enter. I want to see and use next view button (see picture 2) instead of Enter button.

Comment: @t0m i'm sorry didn't get it right, now I see, I managed to do it in one of my projects with this combination  (see edited code), I understand that you tried some combinations but maybe you didn't try this

Comment: This is not multiline `EditText`.