# setOnEditorActionListener() method not working with inputtype textMultiline along with enter button in keyboard

Tags: java, android

I am stuck into a problem that when iam using inputtype as textmultiline in xml and imeiOptions as KEYCODE_ENTER in edittext.Then my setOnEditorActionListener is not working but if i change my inputtype to text then its working fine.Iam not able to understand that why this is not working with textMultiline.
    My Edittext defined in xml is-:

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etremarks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_edittext_pink_border"
            android:fontFamily="@font/share"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="Enter Message"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />


and my code for edittext in java file is-:


 etremarks.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
        etremarks.setImeOptions(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);

        etremarks.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                                          KeyEvent event)
            {
                boolean handled = false;
                if (actionId == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                {
                    // Handle pressing "Enter" key here
                    Toast.makeText(SendBulkSmsToClients.this, etremarks.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    handled = true;
                }
                return handled;
            }
        });
```

Please share your valuable opinions for this problem

thanks

Comment: Maybe this is helpfull for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986387/multi-line-edittext-with-done-action-button/43436446

Comment: not clear in above example.,Basically what i need is when user press enter button in softkeyboard then at that time i have to add some encoding parameters to the edittext.So for that i need editor listener but it's not working with multiline and keycode.enter.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

and in XML:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Source : [Multi-line EditText with Done action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986387/multi-line-edittext-with-done-action-button/41022589#41022589)

Answer (score 0):

add this line `android:imeOptions="actionSend"` and in the code , handle like this below

```
 @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
            sendMessage();
            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;
    }
```