# Using Android:Digits attribute to restrict characters stops action next button working

Tags: android, action, digits

I have a number of EditText fields on an Android app and I've used android:digits to stop invalid characters being input.

eg:
`android:digits="@string/validchars"`
(where "validchars" is a string resource of all the valid characters - eg A-Z, 0-9, and some punctuation )

The problem is, if the user hits the ENTER key on the soft keyboard it used to take them to the next field but since I added android:digits bit this has stopped working. I've tried adding \n to the `validchars` but this just allows Carriage Returns in the single line textboxes (!) so doesn't help. I've tried fiddling with the imeOptions (adding `actionNext` etc) but this doesn't seem to fix it either.
I've read about TextWatchers and InputFilters but both seem to be over-complicated for what I'm trying to do and the `android:digits` bit works fine in stopping the invalid characters.

Has anyone got any ideas?

I'm using Android SDK version 8 and targeting both 2.2 and 2.3.5 devices.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After a bit of poking around with the attributes available for an EditText I found that when I add android:singleLine="true" the ENTER key now moves the focus to the next field, even when a android:digits is restricting the characters entered.  Problem solved! (for me, anyway!)

Comment: Alternatively, if the user desires to have a "done" option instead of next, see this question, which is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919742/android-editview-done-button

Comment: android:singleLine deprecated =( is it any other way?

Comment: I believe you should now use maxLines="1"

Comment: but android:maxLines= 1 doesnt work well with android:digits

Answer (score 0):

Just add "\n" in digits attribute as allow enter key and textMultiLine as inputType

```html
android:inputType="textMultiLine"      android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 \n"
```