# android:digits not allowing next button in keypad

Tags: android, android-keypad

Im using

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz. "
```

and having one more `EditText` in the same screen when i press enter key in keypad the focus doesn't gets changed.

suppose if i remove the

```
 android:digits
```

the enter button works fine and moves to the next edit text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add   `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` in your EditText in xml

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_count"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: not working here. When digits attribute is there, imeOptions doesn't work. why is that ?

Comment: @BugsHappen For a fix try adding android:singleLine="true", reffered from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048007/using-androiddigits-attribute-to-restrict-characters-stops-action-next-button-w

Comment: please add the singleLine true to answer not just in comments. It fixed the issue with digits .

Comment: I can confirm `android:singleLine="true"` fixes it in 2018. `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` does not.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `imeOptions` attribute available for `EditText` in `xml`.

Try the following. It worked in my case.

In **XML**:

```
 <EditText
      android:id="@+id/edit_text1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="45dp"
      android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz. " 
      android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

<EditText
      android:id="@+id/edit_text2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="45dp"/>
```

Then, in **JAVA**:

```
    EditText edit_text1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.edit_text1);

    EditText edit_text2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.edit_text2);

    edit_text1.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {     
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

            boolean handled = false;

            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                edit_text2.requestFocus();
                handled = true;
            }

            return handled;
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

you must be delete 'android:digits' to active the 'android:imeOptions="actionNext"' code.

Answer (score 0):

Just add "\n" in digits attribute as allow enter key and textMultiLine as inputType

android:inputType="textMultiLine"      android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz