# How to enable action button in soft keyboard if the input digit attribute is already given?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Keyboard action button is disabled if input digit attribute is given.How can I enable it?

Below is my code:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/other_minor_complaints"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
android:layout_marginStart="20dp"                                      
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

Comment: Hi just refer to this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588503/androiddigits-not-allowing-next-button-in-keypad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android:digits not allowing next button in keypad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588503/androiddigits-not-allowing-next-button-in-keypad)