# ime option changed after using digits

Tags: android, imeoptions

i have used digits and after using it ime option is changed from actoin next to action next(which is used for multiline).
Here is my code:

```
 <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/acpr_etLiftNo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/tvsize"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_padding"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/default_padding"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:longClickable="false"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:digits="@string/en_validation"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:hint="@string/lift_no"
                    >
                    <requestFocus/>
                    </EditText>
```

Comment: Can Explain properly. what you want?

Comment: I want to use android:imeOptions="actionNext", it works fine if I dont use digits, but if i use digits then android:imeOptions="actionNext", not working properly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11391159/4684984 This might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```