# Cannot figure out how to make android keyboard go away, unless back button is press

Tags: android

I have a EditView.  When some one clicks on the EditView, the only way the keywbaord will go away is if the back button id press.

I saw some apps have it so when the keyboard comes up, there is a button that says done in the lower right hand corner.  When this is press the keyboard goes away.
My app does not do this, does anybody know how they did this?

Also is it possible to have the keyboard go away when the enter key is press, insrad of having it add another line of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use [TextView.setImeOptions()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setImeOptions%28int%29) and pass it actionDone or use the android:imeOptions="actionDone" attribute in your layout.

To close when enter is pressed, use a custom [OnEditorActionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setOnEditorActionListener%28android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener%29). However, it would probably be better to change the enter key to done as above so as to convey what action will occur.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919742/android-editview-done-button).

Comment: Hi,Thank you for taking the time to answer my quastion, I was going around in circles trying to figure it out.

Comment: Hi,How can I " it would probably be better to change the enter key to done as above so as to convey what action will occur."?? also thank you for your info.

Comment: I was simply saying that it would be better to change the enter key to done rather than having the enter key close the keyboard. By changing the key to done, you convey to the user what will happen when they click that button.

Comment: I tried to use the XML version, but it didn't work. I also have `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` in my `EditText`, so not sure if that matters. But adding the `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` doesn't do anything to my return key, and my return key creates new paragraphs, like before. :( Actually I tried to remove the `input` but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Figured it out! You MUST also put `inputType="text"` or else the keyboard will not respond. I added that and my return key turned into a `Done` key. Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext.

Comment: For clarity, the `xml` code to add is `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`. Plus `android:inputType="text"`, as stated above.