# How to change the Softkeyboard "Enter" button Text in android?

Tags: android, android-keypad

I want to set the softkeyboard to "Enter" key text to "Done".
Is there any way to change the text of the enter key of the softkeyboard of the android device? Please suggest if anyone have any idea.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This link tells another approach. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919742/android-editview-done-button/27035249#27035249

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In XML for the `editText` put

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Comment: Then setOnEditorActionListener()

Answer (score 3):

```
    Apply inputType and imeOptions tag in EditText. Here inputType property is the type of data to be inserted and imeOptions is the action. this action may be go to next edittext, search, enter etc. This property change the icon on bottom right corner of the soft keyboard.



 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="user name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="password"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"/>
```

Java Code

```
  EditText userName = findViewById(R.id.username);
                EditText password = findViewById(R.id.password);

// Set the action listener on editText

            userName.setOnEditorActionListener(editorActionListener);
            password.setOnEditorActionListener(editorActionListener);
        }

 // and based on the emeOptions define in EditText add listeners when the 
 //enter key key pressed in softKeyboad 

        private TextView.OnEditorActionListener editorActionListener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                switch (actionId){
                     case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SEARCH", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to  your answer. Code only answers does not server any purpose to the future readers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will add an explanation.