# How to change the default keyboard next arrow into custom name in keyboard?

Tags: android, android-keypad

In my application login screen i need to change the default keyboard last next arrow instead of some text like next,done like this is it possible for android? if anyone know can you answer this question.

Comment: search so before you ask question, so many question already there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100482/how-to-change-the-softkeyboard-enter-button-text-in-android

Comment: i already try that one but till i cant get the next instead of that arrow in keyboard

Comment: on which device you are testing ? i got same issue on some motorola device like motorola atrix

Comment: now i get the solution i change input type in my phone default android  keyboard before i use swipe keyboard thats problem its not changed now i get the output thanks for reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **android:imeActionLabel="YourText"** or **android:imeOptions="actionNext"** property of `EditText`

below is sample code

```
           <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_user"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:hint="@string/userprofile_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/next"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                 />
```

Comment: arrow not changed still is there any other way help i try this 3 hours   i cant change that arrow into next text

Comment: may be we can't change icon but try any other imeOptions instaed of "actionNext" and check

Answer (score 0):

use android:imeOptions="actionGo" with in your EditText view  then click on this edittext view keyboard will appear with Go button

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_bg" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/Username"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/lineView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
            android:background="@color/lineColor" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lineView"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/Password"
            android:imeOptions="actionGo"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i try this keyboard not appear Go button do you know anyother option