# How to allow Multiline Text in Android EditText while restricting input using android:digits?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

With an EditText it is possible to add an entry to support alphanumeric digits like the following:

```
android:digits="@string/alphanumeric_allowed_chars_free_textentry"
```

Where the string is defined as

```
<string name="alphanumeric_allowed_chars_free_textentry">
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-=[];,./~!@#$%^</string>
```

However, as others have noted, when a user sets the `digits` attribute, it can cause the "enter" button to show a return arrow instead of a `next` or `done` button, as described in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919742/android-editview-done-button)

The *typical* solution to get `done` to show up is to set `android:singleLine="true"` and  `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`, but this will only work for an input box which is not a multi-line box.  I have a multi-line edit text and would like to be able to add a `done` button and also fliter using the `digits` attribute.

Does anyone know how to allow an EditText to use digits while also being multiline, while also allowing the return button to show "done"? Android 4.4

Answer (score 0):

What if you modify alphanumeric_allowed_chars_free_textentry to include carriage return (\r, \n)?

Comment: Good idea, I've tried this by adding `\\n` and `\\r` or `&#10;` and/or `&#13;` but it did not help

Comment: adding '\r\n' to 'android:digits' helped me

Answer (score 0):

i was unable to reply / comment to your comment 
So added new answer

in multiline edittext 
after adding \r\n to my digits property
android:digits="1234567890@$%^&*()_+-=qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm:;,.?/|~`{}[]QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM+x÷x€£¥₩×\r\n ●■□⊙☆¤•°《》¿¡\"

i am able to goto nextline on enter as well using the digits property.
below is my axml code "

i was unable to reply / comment to your comment

in multiline edittext after adding \r\n to my digits property android:digits="1234567890@$%^&*()_+-=qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm:;,.?/|~`{}[]QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM+x÷x€£¥₩×\r\n ●■□⊙☆¤•°《》¿¡\"

i am able to goto nextline as well using the digits property .
"

```
<EditText                
                android:id="@+id/NewTask_TaskDescription"
                style="@style/MultiLineTextboxStyle"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_height="151dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:singleLine="false"
                        android:digits="1234567890@$%^&amp;*()_+-=qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm:;,.?/|~`{}[]QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM+x÷x€£¥₩×\r\n ●■□⊙☆¤•°《》¿¡\\" />
```

"