# How to end EditText editing properly in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have EditText widget on my activity.

How should I make/handle "commit" in that text field?

I saw that some applications control keyboard and there is "Done" or "Ok" key instead of "Enter". Maybe this is how should I do it... But I don't know how how to do it.

Comment: This question has been ask a gazillion times. please google before posting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919742/android-editview-done-button

Comment: Check this out it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext