# Android Keyboard style with OK Button

Tags: android, keyboard

I am creating an app and I need help.

I want to create a EditText and when the user open the keyboard to fill the edit text, that keyboard must have the "OK"or "Done" button inside it.

Example:

[image: Example]

Thank you so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make an Android EditView 'Done' button and hide the keyboard when clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919742/how-do-i-make-an-android-editview-done-button-and-hide-the-keyboard-when-click)

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to use ime options action done
2. You need to use single line (although deprecated)

example:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/saveDialogEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890-_ ."
        android:hint="@string/enter_palette_name_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
```