# I need custom Done button on keyboard in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

[image]

Anyone help to add **DONE** *button* on top of *soft keyboard* like above screenshot shows.

Because I need **Enter** and **Done** both button on my **Edit Text**.
So, please *suggest* me If anyone have *Idea*.
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: This may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919742/how-do-i-make-an-android-editview-done-button-and-hide-the-keyboard-when-click

Answer (score 2):

How about just adding a custom Button in the bottom of your UI?

- You can observe layout size changes -> find a case when keyboard appears and disappears (Remember its different case from screen rotation, different screen proportion)
- Based on keyboard hidden/shown event you can show/hide your custom UI.

I guess only problem is, you don't know what is keyboard view background. But its definitely better than writting your own keyboard, AFAIK you can't add views to keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a custom keyboard for that. For custom keyboard you can try here:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

https://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-create-an-android-custom-keyboard-application/

http://www.blackcj.com/blog/2016/03/30/building-a-custom-android-keyboard/

Answer (score 0):

You would like to have an easy solution? Then integrate your "Done" button in your layout. Your layout should look like this (short version):

```
<LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
  <ScrollView layout_weight="1"> <-- if needed, use FrameLayout else
    place your Layout here
  </ScrollView>
  <YourDoneButton/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Your Button will stack on the top of the keyboard. I assume, that the user should be able to click of the "Done" button even if the keyboard is hidden. If not, you can hide it if your `EditText` is not focused.